# Linking to Windows API's PatchAPI

Tags: winapi, linker, libraries, name-decoration

I would like to use [Windows API's PatchAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417345.aspx#patchapi) in order to apply some patches.
Applying of patches is implemented in mspatcha.dll, which should be located in one's system32 folder.

After reading in various places, such as their ref and googling, I have yet to find the right way to link to this DLL. I would like to link statically, dealing with LoadLibrary seems messy and sort of defeats the purpose of their patchapi.h header. Since I have found no .lib file I am to link to, I created my own using the following commands:

1) dumpbin /exports C:\windows\system32\mspatcha.dll

2) Create a mspatcha.def file, write an "EXPORTS" line, followed by one line for each function name that appears in the output of dumpbin

3) lib /def:mspatcha.def /out:mspatcha.lib

Although I'm sure this is not the right way to statically link with patchapi, I have not found the right way to do so.
Anyway, after following these steps and writing a simple testcase made of a single call to ApplyPatchToFileExA(), I still get a linker error on the symbol _ApplyPatchToFileA@16.
Taking a look at the exported symbols of my newly created mspatcha.lib, it appears that the functions use the wrong name convention

> D:\tmp\mspatcha>dumpbin /exports mspatcha.lib|find "ApplyPatchToFileExA"
>
> ```
>              _ApplyPatchToFileExA
> ```

Unless I'm wrong, this indicates that the lib exported functions using cdecl whereas the dll is using stdcall (or at least  is declaring the function as _stdcall). See: [C name decoration in Microsoft Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C_name_decoration_in_Microsoft_Windows).

My questions are: what is the right way to use mspatcha.dll in my application and what was wrong with my process of creating a lib from a dll so I can do static linking?

The detailed output of my terminal can be found here: http://pastebin.com/q4FV4Se6

Comment: Please distinguish the terms "statically imported" and "statically linked". The former means that the loader will resolve any imported functions before the binary gets control (it may fail). The latter means that the actual object code gets linked into your final binary image.

Comment: I'm a bit confused that `lib.exe` should create decorated names like that from the DEF file you give. Have you tried to link against this .lib and then inspect the import directory of the resulting binary?

Comment: Try to use this little tool: http://vortex.masmcode.com/files/def2lib11.zip - it takes the decorated name in the .def files so that both the linker and the loader will be happy.

Comment: @status actually the correct term is "implicit dynamic linking". This contrasts with "explicit dynamic linking" which is GetProcAddress and "static linking" which everyone understands.

Answer (score 0):

As a point of terminology you are attempting to link implicitly rather than statically which means something quite different.

If you really can't get hold of a .lib file then one easy way to generate one is to create a dummy DLL with empty stubs for each function. Call the DLL mspatcha.dll. Make sure you use a .def file and stdcall.

When you've built the DLL, throw it away but keep the .lib file!

I've done this in the past to generate .lib files for DLLs built with tool chains that don't emit .lib files.

The technique that you used only works for cdecl functions.

Comment: That's overkill. `lib.exe` can be used to create an import `.lib` by simply using a `.def` (module definition) file. No need to create a dummy DLL at all. It's what the OP is doing, so the problem is with the calling convention as suspected.

Comment: Side-note: the technique he used does not only work for `__cdecl`. I've been using it many times over with `__stdcall`.

Comment: @status your comment about cdecl is contradicted here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313

Comment: @David: that's great. But how do you explain that it worked for kdcom.dll and bootvid.dll the many times I did use it? I had a Perl script that parsed the output of dumpbin and passed that to lib. There was no additional magic involved. And those DLLs use `__stdcall`.

Comment: @status I don't have an explanation. But you can see why I stated what I did.

Comment: @status It's also pretty simple to write a script to stub out a header file to generate a .lib. I have a Perl script to do precisely that for a DLL that I develop that is written in Delphi and hence does not emit a .lib.